# Use a for loop in an object with an array with an object in it node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, for-loop

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I just can't. I have an object, which has an array in it, which has objects in it. I'm trying to figure out how to use a for loop to search through the array's objects. Heres my attempt:

```
var obj = {
    array: [
        {"meme" : "123", "mememe" : "456"},
        {"meme" : "234", "mememe" : "567"}
    ]
}

console.log(obj.array)
for(var i in obj) {
    console.log(i);
};
```

This  code logs the array like this:

```
[ { meme: '123', mememe: '456' },
  { meme: '234', mememe: '567' } ]
```

Then it just logs:

```
0
1
```

What I want it to log is something like

```
{ meme: '123', mememe: '456' }
{ meme: '234', mememe: '567' }
```

So I can then do something with this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to loop through the obj.array you can use:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.array.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj.array[1]);
}
```

or

```
for (var object of obj.array) {
    console.log(object);
}
```

or

```
obj.array.forEach(function(object) { console.log(object) });
```

if you want iterate over every array that might be in *obj* you can do this:

```
for (var property in obj) {
    // gets all the propertie-names of object (in this case just 'array')
    for(var object of obj[property]) {
        // iterates through all the items in the array (in this case just obj['array'])
        console.log(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array with a [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and use the index for accessing the objects.

Mabye you have a look here, too: [Why is using `for ....in` with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

```js
var obj = {
        array: [
            { meme: "123", mememe: "456"},
            { meme: "234", mememe: "567"}
        ]
    },
    i

for (i = 0; i < obj.array.length; i++) {
    console.log(obj.array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution.

```
var obj = {
    array: [
        {"meme" : "123", "mememe" : "456"},
        {"meme" : "234", "mememe" : "567"}
    ]
}

obj.array.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
})
```

And the JSFiddle link (just turn on the dev tools (ctrl+shift+i on windows)
https://jsfiddle.net/4cn6s3tf/